# AWS Data Pipeline Creation Error Code: Throttling-- Rate Exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-data-pipeline

Error Image 1 -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YSg.png

Error Image 2 ->https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bZkU.png

Comment: You need to reach out to AWS Support with this info

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Also, I noticed that there is increase in AWS Identity access management API error rates. Maybe it is because of that. Thanks Prabhakar!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-limits.html#dp-limits-web-service

> CreatePipeline    1 call per second   100 calls

you likely just need to wait a few moments and try again.